# NoSuchElementException in Stack trace, tried some other solutions in the community still not helpful

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8

Other possible solutions I got in different forums are not working.  Here is my code.

```
class javaFX extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX app");
        Label label = new Label("Hello World, JavaFX !");
        Scene scene = new Scene(label, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the StackTrace. It  is showing NoSuchElementException which is a bit weird.

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class xlSheets.javaFX
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xlSheets.javaFX.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$165(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Your `Application` subclass needs to be `public`. OT: please follow proper Java naming conventions. (Also, the stack trace is showing a `NoSuchMethodException`, not a `NoSuchElementException`.)

Comment: ohh .. __DO NOT__ repost a question, instead edit the first to make it answerable, at the very least __LEARN__ from the comments (you still violate java naming conventions, stop that _immediately_!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.launch()` method uses reflection to create an instance of the `Application` subclass, calling its constructor taking no arguments.

According to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)) the `Appplication` subclass

> must be a public subclass of `Application` with a public no-argument constructor

So in order for this to work, both the `Application` subclass and the constructor (if explicitly defined) need to be declared `public`.

The following fixes the problem (I also changed the class name to conform to Java naming conventions):

```
public class JavaFX extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX app");
        Label label = new Label("Hello World, JavaFX !");
        Scene scene = new Scene(label, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean by reflection, some other forums said the same things but I couldn't get it.

Comment: @KaustuvaKumarSahu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: _stuff which i couldn't understand_ then it's time for learning java/fx language basics ... you find this most simple App code in literally __every__ introductory tutorial on fx, this site is not the place to repeat it, normally ;)

Comment: Ok ,i get it but why is changing the class to public helping it.

Comment: @KaustuvaKumarSahu The underlying reason is that `Application.launch()` calls [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)), which only finds publicly-accessible constructors. However, you don't need to dig into those details, simply read the documentation for the method you called (i.e. `Application.launch()`) that is throwing the exception. See edit.